# How to filter relationships based on their fields in response using Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, serialization

I have three models: House, Resident, Car.
Each House has many Residents (One to Many). Each Resident has 0 or 1 cars (One to One). 
For my frontend, I want to display all the residents of a house that have a car. 
Django Rest Framework suggests using Filtering, but this only works at the top level. For example, in my `HouseDetailView(generics.RetrieveAPIView)`, I can only modify the queryset of the House model itself. I want to be able to modify the queryset of the Resident (`resident_queryset.exclude(car=None)`).

```
class HouseDetailView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
  queryset = House.objects.all()
  serializer_class = HouseSerializer
```

Can/Should I do this all in one request?
Are query parameters my only way of filtering?

Comment: can you please share your models.py

Comment: House has a `name`, Resident has a `name` and `ForeignKey` to House, and Car has a `name` and `OneToOne` relationship to Resident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# If you want to display all the residents of a house that have a car, then you should query the car model


class CarDetailView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Car.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarSerializer


serializers.py

class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # get the resident details (name)
    resident_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_resident_name')

    def get_resident_name(self, obj):
        return obj.resident.name


    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ("name", "resident_name")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) to filter related objects:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

class HouseDetailView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
  serializer_class = HouseSerializer

  def get_queryset(self):
      return House.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('resident_set', queryset=Resident.objects.exclude(car__isnull=True)))
```

Note `resident_set` is reverse name for `Resident` model and may be different for you base on [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) argument.